# How to have href load info from xml file in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I am sure this is an easy question I have searched for about day.

I have an xml file (it is local) and it contains fields such as :

LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, GRADE, DISABILITY

I am using the iscroll example with the a-zindex navigator on the side(mimics iphone contact list ui).

```
     <ul>

       <li><a href="#details">FIRSNAME LASTNAME</a></li>
```

my question is

when a href="#details" is loaded how do i populate the page with the details information from the LASTNAME?

Comment: need more information.  is there a click event?  do you go to the server to get data?  if yes then what language? if not then at what point in the page life cycle to you want to populate the details?

Comment: Currently nothing.  Was planning on adding the click event based on the li chosen. I am lost